# Alternative proof for convexity of a set

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Consider a set
$$
    \mathcal{C} = \{(x, y)| a \leq x \leq b, y < 0, f(x) y \leq c\}
$$
with $c > 0$ and the assumption that the reciprocal $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ is negative and convex for $a \leq x \leq b$. Convexity of this set is not too difficult to show, since the first two inequalities are not very troublesome and the third can be rearranged as
$$
    \frac{c}{f(x)}-y\leq 0,
$$
where the l.h.s. is a convex function of $(x,y)$ for $a\leq x \leq b$ due to my previous assumptions about $\frac{1}{f(x)}$.
Is there an alternative way to prove convexity of $\mathcal{C}$ without involving the reciprocal of $f(x)$, but rather only similar (implied) assumptions on $f(x)$? My motivation behind this is that I would like to investigate similar sets in higher dimensions, e.g., $y_1, y_2 <0$ and $f_1(x)y_1+f_2(x)y_2\leq c$ and check what conditions on $f_1(x), f_2(x)$ would be sufficient to produce a similarly convex set $\mathcal{C}$.
Note that a simple rearrangement like
$$
    f(x)y-c \leq 0
$$
did not lead me to the desired solution, since the l.h.s is not a convex function of $(x,y)$ on the considered set. (I checked the Hessian of $f(x)y$, which is indefinite.)

Comment: From what I get, $f(x) < 0$. But in that the case, $[f(x)]^{-1}$ is not neccessarily convex. Indeed, let $g = 1/f$. Then, $g' = -f' f^{-2}$ and $g'' = - f'' f^{-2} + 2(f')^2 f^{-3}$. Moreover, a wild guess is that your $f(x)y$ is quasi-convex. The sum of quasi convex functions are generally not quasi convex.

Comment: You're right about convexity of $g(x) = [f(x)]^-1$. I had originally made assumptions about $g(x)<0, g''(x)>0$ but stated their implication $f(x)<0, f''(x)<0$ here (which should actually be true), since the question was focused on getting rid of the reciprocal in the prove anyway. However, the inverse implication (from concavity of $f$ to convexity of $g$) does not hold and I have now updated the question to correctly reflect my original assumptions.
Thank you for the hint regarding quasi-convexity. I will definitely check that.

Comment: By the way, if your whole problem allows to perform a change of variable such as $y_i = -e^{z_i}$, it becomes easier to obtain conditions on the $f_i$s so that $-f_i(x)e^{z_i}$ is convex.